# Javascript Recursion: How to the instance of parent access of the child node

Tags: javascript, recursion

i'm trying to build the logic to get access to the all parent nodes of the child I've currently access to via recursion,but not able to do so. here's what I've done so far:

Here's my array:

```
var results = [{
  "key": 1,
  "name": "A",
  "child": [{
    "key": 2,
    "name": "A1",
    "child": [{
      "key": 1473591350189,
      "name": "A11"
    }]
  }, {
    "key": 10,
    "name": "A2",
    "child": []
  }]
}, {
  "key": 66,
  "name": "B",
  "child": [{
    "key": 67,
    "name": "B1",
    "child": [{
      "key": 68,
      "name": "B11",
      "child": [{
        "key": 69,
        "name": "B111",
        "child": []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];
```

Now my logic is for iteration:

```
function recursionFn(results, parentNode) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var _node = results[i];
    if (_node.child.length > 0) {
      console.log('Name: ' + _node.name + ' First Childs: ' + _node.child.length);
      if (parentNode)
        console.log('ParentNode: ' + parentNode.name);
    }
    if (_node.child.length > 0)
      recursionFn(_node.child, _node);
    if (_node.child.length == 0) {
      console.log('Name: ' + _node.name + ' Second Childs: ' + _node.child.length);
      if (parentNode)
        console.log('ParentNode: ' + parentNode.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Here I'm getting the immediate parent of the current child I'm in but how do I get access to all the parents of that child. For instance, if the relationship is:
**A -> A1 -> A11**
Then how do I get access to all parents of **A11**? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Walking up the parents is better done in a loop rather than recursion.
Walking all nodes in a hierarchy is (arguably) better done with recursion than in a loop.

I suggest this to walk parents

```
function navParents(node)
{
    if(!node)
       return;
    while(node != null) {
       /* do something with node here */
       node = node.parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: His data structure does not have a reverse pointer to parent nodes. So to find parents you first must do a recursive walk to find the child. The algorithm he is looking for is interestingly used more often in game programming or network optimization: Dijkstra's algorithm (the heuristically guided version, A* is usually used in pathfinding for game AI)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative recursive approach for seaching the parent nodes of a wanted node, which is defined in a callback.

This proposal uses [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because if a node is found, then the iteration can be stopped for this level.

The result array contains all parent nodes from the root to the final node.

```js
function getParentNodes(tree, callback) {
    var nodes = [];
    tree.some(function iter(a) {
        if (callback(a) || Array.isArray(a.child) && a.child.some(iter)) {
            nodes.unshift(a);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return nodes;
}

var results = [{ key: 1, name: "A", child: [{ key: 2, name: "A1", child: [{ key: 1473591350189, name: "A11" }] }, { key: 10, name: "A2", child: [] }] }, { key: 66, name: "B", child: [{ key: 67, name: "B1", child: [{ key: 68, name: "B11", child: [{ key: 69, name: "B111", child: [] }] }] }] }];

console.log(getParentNodes(results, function (o) { return o.name === 'A11'; }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Schols, the getParents(results, 'A11') call to function has a name string for parent in the arguements. I don't have access to the parent's name directly.

Comment: @CodeKaro, hello, my name is *nina*. please add, what you expect with your function. what are the inputs and the expected outputs?

Comment: the inputs is the array. There is a flag I set to the child node based on some condition, that I want to set to all of it's parents. That's why I want to backtrack to all the parents of this child.

Comment: maybe this edit helps you more. it uses a callback for identifying the target note and returns all nodes from the root to the target root.